# Am I crazy or is it actually going this fast? (MultiThreading)

Tags: python, multithreading, tornado

```
from tornado import httpclient
import time

start = time.time()

for x in range(1000):
    httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient().fetch("https://www.google.com", method="GET")

print ('{0} seconds'.format(time.time() - start))
```

Result `1.11500000954 seconds`

I wrote this to see how fast I can send 1000 requests to any site (I chose google) and I don't know why, but I feel like I did something wrong and its not actually going this quick, if I did do something wrong, could someone point out my error?

Thank you!

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but there is no need for `x = 0`

Comment: The requests are made asynchronously and you don't seem to be waiting for all 1000 requests to complete. Therefore, I bet your timer is just the synchronous version of iterating over a range of 1000 elements

Comment: So, @niro.... what do you think will happen when all 1000 threads come back at the same time?

Comment: Reacting on answers and comments is obviously overrated.

Answer (score 6):

Well, yes, you spun off 1000 *asynchronous* requests to Google and timed that.  You did not, however, time the overhead of actually making the HTTP call.  That would require a [callback-type](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/httpclient.html#tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient) of handler.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run this yet, so I could be wrong, but fetch() is an asynchronous method that takes a callback, and the callback is what handles the response from the server when it comes. In other words, I'm pretty sure all you're doing here in this ~1 second is creating the representations of the requests — you're definitely not waiting for responses, and I'm not sure you're necessarily even sending the requests. I don't know the internal implementation here, but you might be buffering them in some sense, or you could be making attempts to send them as fast as possible but some/many are failing — and you don't really know what's actually happening, because these asynchronous requests are "fire and forget".

If you want to know how many USEFUL requests you can send, as in ones that will reach the server and get a response, you'd need to do the timing in a callback, not in the thread that's creating the requests.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers already pointed out, `tornado` works asynchronously. You have to run the requests in an [`IOLoop`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/ioloop.html#ioloop-objects). Please note that this has nothing to do with multithreading. The requests are executed in parallel, but within a single thread (the core feature of async IO).

This is how it could be done:

```
from tornado import httpclient, ioloop
import time

start = time.time()

loop = ioloop.IOLoop.instance()
N = 10
finished = 0

def callback(f):
    global finished
    finished += 1
    print('%d requests finished' % finished)
    if finished >= N:
        loop.stop()
        print ('{0} seconds'.format(time.time() - start))

for x in range(N):
    f = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient().fetch("https://www.google.com",
                                           method="GET")
    loop.add_future(f, callback)

loop.start()
```

Your code only creates 1000 request objects ([`Future`](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/concurrent.html#tornado.concurrent.Future) objects to be precise), that are actually never send to the server.